# Business timings for each record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Business time](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) is great gem but I wanted to know can I use it for multiple business hours for multiple records for example I have multiple records of restaurants which have different business timings like this

```
[
  Mon: {
    morning: {
      from: 9:00 am, to: 12:00 pm
    },
    noon:{
      from: 2:00 am, to: 5:00 pm
    },
    night{
      from: 7:00pm to: 11:pm
    }
  },
  Tue: {
    morning: {
      from: 10:00 am, to: 12:00 pm
    },
    noon:{
      from: 1:00 am, to: 5:00 pm
    },
    night: {
      from: 7:00pm to: 11:pm
    }
  },
  Wed: {
    morning: {
      from: 9:30 am, to: 12:00 pm
    },
    noon:{
      from: 1:30 am, to: 5:00 pm
    },
    night:{
      from: 7:00pm to: 11:pm
    }
  },
  Thu:{
    morning: {
      from: 9:00 am, to: 01:00 pm
    },
    noon:{
      from: 1:00 am, to: 5:00 pm
    },
    night:
    {
      from: 7:00pm to: 11:pm
    }
  },
  Fri:{
    morning: {
      from: 9:00 am, to: 01:00 pm
    },
    noon:{
      from: 1:00 am, to: 5:00 pm
    },
    night:{
      from: 7:00pm to: 11:pm
    }
  }
  Sat: off
  Sun: off
]
```

Can I use this gem for to implement this? if yes then How? or is there any other gem can do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

That gem allows to do that too. See below if it helps

`three_day_weekend = Date.parse("July 5th, 2010")
BusinessTime::Config.holidays << three_day_weekend
friday_afternoon = Time.parse("July 2nd, 2010, 4:50 pm")
tuesday_morning = 1.business_hour.after(friday_afternoon)`

## plus, we can change the work week:

## July 9th in 2010 is a Friday.

`BusinessTime::Config.work_week = [:sun, :mon, :tue, :wed, :thu]
thursday_afternoon = Time.parse("July 8th, 2010, 4:50 pm")
sunday_morning = 1.business_hour.after(thursday_afternoon)`

Comment: and what if every restaurant has its own business hours

Comment: Then I think you can define a field in restaurant table which will save their working timings and define a class method in model which will tell you working timing for that restaurant